# Usage of PHP session_id with account system

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

So, I started to develop a website on my local server...

I wrote a Register/Login system with a MySQL database, in PHP. I know that i have to use sessions for it, but i dont really understand them.

1. If i just start a session without an ID, it will generate a random
   ID?
2. As I think, I should generate the ID and start the session after the
   SQL checking (pw and username) but before it throws the user to the
   next page. Am I right?
3. Once I generate it as I mentioned in those questions, Should I store it in a SQL table or something?
4. Will they die automatically or I have to kill them somehow? (except the manual logout page by the user click) I've read somewhere that they will die by the time, but as I think I have to set it up somehow.
5. Where are they??? (I know, this is a highly retarded question) They are in the client or the server?

Yeah... I know, I should do something else... Well, I just need a source where they are documented for this kind of usage, or a description like this: Generate -> store -> check every time when the page changes -> they will kill themself automatically.

Comment: 1. yes, 2.let php do it for you 3.do you need to? 4.yes, they have time limits, 5.on your server. https://devzone.zend.com/16/php-101-part-10-a-session-in-the-cookie-jar/

Comment: as your new to SO know that this is going to be closed as its to broad, check the help center for how to ask.

Comment: Part 1) Session id's are randomly generated, you don't need to worry about their IDs. You reference Session data as an array of values that can be passed from page to page.

Comment: See [The Definitive Guide to Form-Based Website Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication). It's quite comprehensive.

Comment: Part 2) That choice is yours, in time, experience will guide you.

Comment: Part 3) No, the session data is stored in a file on the filesystem, referenced by the session id. Again, you do not need to worry about this. Let PHP worry.

Comment: Part 4) You can manually kill sessions with `unset` and you should be aware that sessions will die when a time value has elapsed (30 mins or so) or when the browser the session is associated with is closed.

Comment: Part 5) Sessions are stored in the file system, usually under the `/tmp` directory . It is wise to give them a custom directory home but its another aspect that you can leave well alone until you're more experienced with them.

Comment: @showdev that's such a beautiful SO post . Good link `:-)`

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, I've been smarter by 5 minutes of reading the comments than 2 hours searching. 

I know this is not the typical form of a question here, but this question was my first and hopefully the last aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you start the session on every page. The session is initialised on the first page the user visits. A session ID is generated whenever the session is initialised, so having a session ID as a login identifier is no good. The session itself, like all PHP code, is processed server-side.

So every page should have `session_start()` at the very top.

The thing you want to do is store session variables, for example `$_SESSION['username']`, and check whether the user is logged in or not with something in the trend of `if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])`

Session die whenever you call 'session_abort()' or the browser is closed. You can also call `session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");` or something similar for a session duration (before `session_start();`), where the 3600 is the number of seconds the session is active.

So one simple solution could be:

**session.php**

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['username') {
  echo "Hello";
} else {
  echo $loginform;
}
```

**randompage.php**

```
include "session.php";
```

Comment: You're great! Thanks.